# C# Lambda Expression Generator Using Angular

Tags: c#, angular, lambda

I am using following library for my rule engine implementation. You define your code in JSON format and it convert from JSON string to C# code and run the code.

Library: https://github.com/microsoft/RulesEngine

```
Sample Json:
-------------
 // Assume we have an object "Object1" with property "Name".
{
  "Name":"VTPhase",
  "Expression":"Object1.Name.Substring(7, 1)"
}
```

At runtime the expression would be compiled into C# code and would assign the value of expression to variable name "VTPhase". This approach is fine for person having programming background.

However, Is there any way to generate lambda expression from UI for non programming background person so that user can create new expression as per requirements. I have tried multiple UI controls but all supports simple AND/OR operations or simple query builders. I couldn't find any that supports generation of Lambda expressions for C# in angular. Is there any tool or control available that can be extended or support such functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done.

If the non-programmers use the tool, they will really be programming and will have to deal with the complexity involved.

Robert C. Martin concisely summarized this on the first page of his book "Clean Code":

There Will Be Code

One might argue that a book about code is somehow behind the times—that code is no longer the issue; that we should be concerned about models and requirements instead. Indeed some have suggested that we are close to the end of code. That soon all code will be generated instead of written. That programmers simply won't be needed because business people will generate programs from specifications.

Nonsense! We will never be rid of code, because code represents the details of the requirements. At some level those details cannot be ignored or abstracted; they have to be specified. And specifying requirements in such detail that a machine can execute them is programming. Such a specification is code.